# Typescript optional field vs field that can be undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Whats the difference between `optional` field and `T | undefined` field?

```
export interface Demo {
  field1: string | undefined
  field2?: string
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having on optional field will not require you to include that particular property when you try to initialise the object with type Demo.

In Scenerio A, field1 is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) which allows the property to contain a value of type `string`, or `undefined`.

```
export interface Demo {
  field1: string | undefined;
}
```

When you try to initialise an object of type Demo, you will need to explicitly include the property, `field1`, with the required type defined on the interface.

```
demo: Demo = {
  field1: undefined
}
```

Whereas for Scenario B, whereby `field2` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties),

```
export interface Demo {
  field2?: string;
}
```

You will not be required to include the property `field2` when you defined an object of type `Demo`.

```
demo: Demo = {}
```

Comment: in short: explicit vs implicit field declaration?

Comment: Yes, you are right! But do note that for the optional properties, you are still required to supply the optional property with values of the type that is defined on the interface.